# width inherit doesn't fill parent when using calc()

Tags: html, css, css-calc

I am trying to make a div expand to the width of the parent. The parent has a `calc()` on it. Why doesn't the child expand to the width of the parent? If I remove calc and set an actual value it works fine. Is there some trick for getting this to work?

I assume that the child is also running `calc(100% - 200px)`

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.nav {
  width: calc(30% - 16px);
  height: 2000px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.nav>ul {
  width: inherit;
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: simply don't set width .. you inherted the calc here, so it's working fine ..inspect the element and play with the value 200px then you will undertstand

Comment: I updated my code. I forgot to mention that I am also using `fixed`

Comment: now it's because the margin of body :) make it 0 and you will have what you want ;)

Comment: Hmmm... It works here but not on my page...

Comment: well simply take into consideration that the blue one consider his width relative to screen width .. and the red one to container width ... so for sure you have something else

Comment: Okay, I was able to create a snippet that mimics the issue. could you please look

Comment: ok so let me edit my answer :)

Comment: check now the update ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the above comments I am going to elaborate more. It's clear that the `ul` inherited the `calc(30% - 16px)` from its parent and both calculation are different which is logic:

The `nav` has a static position so his width is relative to its container and here it's the `.wrapper` and this one has a width of 75% from its container which is the body so the final width of nav is **`(width-body*0.75)*0.3 - 16px`**.

The `ul` has a fixed position so its width is relative to widow/screen width and since the body has 8px margin by default the width of body is slightly different than the browser width and we can say that `browser-width=width-body + 16px` and thus the width of `ul` is **`(width-body + 16px)*0.3 - 16px`**.

So we can clearly see that the width of `ul` is bigger than the width of `nav`.

---

In order to fix this issue we need to solve the equation :

```
(width-body + 16px)*0.3 - 16px = (width-body*0.75)*0.3 - 16px
```

But this is not the adequate solution as we will end with a **unique negative value** (`-64px`) which is not possible!

Another idea is to adjust the width of the fixed element.

Let's first remove the body margin to make this easier and we will have the new equation:

```
(width-body)*0.3 - 16px = (width-body*0.75)*0.3 - 16px
```

Now we are simply missing the `0.75` factor, so we can simply add it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.nav {
  width: calc(30% - 16px);
  height: 2000px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.nav>ul {
  width: calc((30% * 0.75) - 16px);
  background: blue;
  position: fixed;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

By the way I suspect that you want to have the same behavir as the `sticky` position so you can try it. Simply pay attention to [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.nav {
  width: calc(30% - 16px);
  height: 2000px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}

.nav>ul {
  background: blue;
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! Is there any way to get it to work on different sized `.nav` and wrappers? I am using scss so I have this `width: calc((16.6666% * 0.65) - #{$cell-margin * 2});`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn yes sure ;) in this case consider both equation with all the variable then simply add the missing ones ... as you can see in this case we keep the 30% which is the same and multiply with 0.75 which is equivalent to the 75% of the wrapper. Simple maths :)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn by the way, you know the sticky position ? as it's like you want to implement it

Comment: Okay thanks I will mess around with it some, thanks for the start!

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn check my last update, added it at the end ;)

Comment: Sticky works even better than what I wanted: `position: sticky;top: 0;`